# How to adjust Synaptics touchpad in 18.04

Tags: touchpad, 18.04

Ever since I installed Bionic Beaver last week, my touchpad cursor freezes, disappears, stutters, trips when crossing UI elements, and gets stuck to the edge of the screen. When I used 14.04 I was able to smooth things out using synclient, but that's not available out of the software store anymore.

Is there any way in 18.04 to get the kind of touchpad control that I used to have with synclient?

Comment: It makes a difference if you are running Wayland or X11. Also there may be differences if you are using Gnome or Unity desktop. Could you add more details about your installation?

Comment: This other question just appeared on the radar and might be of interest to you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/832094/synaptics-touchpadd-drivers-for-16-04

Comment: Thanks, WinEunuuchs2Unix. I'm using Gnome on X11. I booted into Wayland for a session but the problems were there as well. I went and looked at the link you provided and while it didn't help me directly some of the links  it contained pointed to possible solutions. I guess I'll work my way through those.