# Two touchpads in xinput (No kinetic, Smooth scrolling)

Tags: drivers

I am having some troubles in my xinput list. the problem is I have two touchpads signed in. (The issue was in ubuntu desktop in 18.04, 18.10, 19.04 and 19.10 and 20.04)

`Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0740:00 06CB:7E7E Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]`

touchpad works fine but I don't have kinetic smooth scrolling which I had it on Xubuntu 19.10 and 20.04

`Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0740:00 06CB:7E7E Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0740:00 06CB:7E7E Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]`

How can I make my xinput configuration like the Xubuntu (second list)

Note: I checked [Dell's documentary](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-lt/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en) which didn't work out because I don't have `/usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d/*synaptics-quirks.conf` file which it was refering to.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem,

basically synaptic drivers was smoother in scrolling on my dell-inspiron 5378. So I installed synaptic drivers by using

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

after the installation and rebooting my keyboard didn't work so I needed to install input devices again by using

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

After installing these two reboot your laptop and Everything will work just fine.

**Note: If you have a problem in Natural horizontal scrolling after implementing synaptic drivers, you can use**

```
synclient
```

to see the value of **HorizScrollDelta** and make it as negative by using command down below. ex: if HorizScrollDelta=28 then

```
synclient HorizScrollDelta=-28
```

Add it as a startup command whenever you boot.

If you didn't see any affects of synclient. you can use

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add

```
# remove SynPS/2 Synaptics Touchpad because we want the mouse to work over IC2b
blacklist psmouse
```

save it and exit. In the terminal use

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to apply the changes and then reboot.

**Sources:**

[keyboard not working fix](https://www.askubuntu.com/questions/688445/laptop-keyboard-stopped-working)

[synclient not working](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=229932)

[synaptic touchpad drivers  install](https://www.askubuntu.com/questions/832094/synaptics-touchpadd-drivers-for-16-04)

[Horizontal natural scrolling enable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1767995)